# Why does a question get closed as a duplicate when other close reasons where also suggested?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104302/reschedule-interview#comment322654_104302) was [closed as a duplicate](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/104302/revisions) of [this quesiton](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p). However, I felt it was far from being a duplicate and wanted to close it as being off topic as the person is asking us to write an email for them. That's far too personal and won't necessarily help other people visiting the site.

I did a vote to close, other topic and gave a reason, as can be seen in [my comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104302/reschedule-interview#comment322654_104302). However, the question received enough close votes for Off Topic and took the highest number of votes for being the duplicate. It now shows my name, and others, against that close reason, but I wholeheartedly disagree with that reason. Is there no other way to show the close reason was disputed between different subjects? I'm not really happy with my name being attached to a reason I didn't select, espcially when I don't agree with it.

Comment: I've always had a problem with this as well, and not just with duplicates. There's an old question on this at Meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason

Comment: Though it actually looks like it's been [partially resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303456/260884), just not for duplicates...

Comment: This is just how closing works. The meta threads linked above are pretty comprehensive. I thought we also had a meta post on "don't reopen questions just to close them for the 'correct' close reason" but can't find it at the moment. I think the general sentiment on this site is that it's better to close as a dupe even if the question is off-topic or otherwise poor, though I personally disagree on that.

Comment: @Lilienthal I can understand that, however I'm not a fan of having words put in my mouth when I didn't say them, especially when I disagree with them. Dukeling also didn't agree with he Dupe, but it's been marked as if that's how they chose to close it, which seems terribly wrong

Comment: @Draken Unfortunately, that's how those SE guys decided the system should work, and it is not just with duplicates. It has happened quite often that I vote one close reason, and the final close reason chosen is a different one but I am included in the list of close voters. It is best to just make peace with it, because those guys never listen, and always use strange excuses to justify their shoddy site design.

Comment: @Draken I get the sentiment, but in this case this is a pretty classic case of a poor question regarding following up on an interview process and it's pretty common for those questions to be closed as dupes of that parent question, regardless of quality.

Comment: @Lilienthal This has nothing to do with the quality of that particular question or what the close reason should or should not have been; this is about the close notification stating that users did things they did not do.

Comment: @DavidK I'm aware, but that's an issue to raise on main meta which is something many people appear to have tried and failed. I'm just commenting on the particular case that prompted this question because it's a classic example on this site and bound to come up more. And because if memory serves this kind of duplicate closing was once considered a good practice. (Can't seem to find a meta thread on it though)

Answer (score 1):

Of the five close votes, two were for primarily opinion-based, two were for duplicate, and one was for off-topic.  When there are multiple reasons, SE reports the most-popular reason (breaking a tie if necessary, as in this case).  Unfortunately it attributes that reason to all five close-voters, except in the case of custom off-topic reasons where the further information about the specific reason is shown with only the users who chose it.

The incorrect attribution has been [raised on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/162102).  I agree that it's frustrating to have the site put words in your mouth.